# html created by javascript doesnt work -- sliders dont slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, fullpage.js

I am learning Javascript and jQuery as I go along so Im having a bit of trouble. I am [making a one page site][1] using [fullPage.js][2] and Im getting the data for the site via JSON from WordPress. Eventually I want to compile this signle page site with cordova to make a mobile app.

Problems:

FullPage.js comes with right/left sliders and Id like to use them to display the content within each section of the one page site. But, when I try and create the slides `<div class="slide">` from a loop of post using javascript and JSON, I cant get the slides to render as slides. All I get is a bunch of div's with the class "slide" attached to them, which does nothing.

Here is an example, It gets Tweets that are turned into WordPress post and Id like each tweet to be a slide, so you can swipe through the recent tweets. How do I get the slide div's that are created in the javascript loop:

```
     <!-- TWITTER POST JSON -->
         <script type="text/javascript">
          var tweeturl = "http://ngaio.dogpatchmedia.com/api/get_posts/?posts_per_page=10&post_type=tweet";

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'GET',
                    url: tweeturl,
                    complete: function(){                    
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        var response = data; //JSON.parse(data);

                        //loop through posts
                        for(var i = 0; i != response.posts.length; i++) {

                        //get each element in the array
                        var post = response.posts[i];

                        // post vars
                        var tweetContent = post.content;

                        // output stuff so we can see things
                        $("#twitter").append('<div class="slide"><div class="large-12 small-12 columns testimonial"><div class="twitterQuote"><p>' + tweetContent + '</p></div><div class="twitter"><div class="photo"><img src="img/twitterLogo.png"> </div></div></div></div>').trigger('create');

                        }


                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                    
                        alert("Error");

                    }

                });
      </script>

  <!-- TWITTER (SLIDER) -->

     <div class="section"><div class="row" id="twitter"></div></div>
```

Notes:

[You can see the full site here](http://ngaio.dogpatchmedia.com/www)

[FullPage.Js docs can be found here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: depending on the utility you're using to make the sliders, you'll need to initialize the sliders after inserting the new html

Comment: Alternatively some slider API's have methods to add slides. Check slider docs. If no images available on page load though is better to just initialize slider in ajax success after slides appended

Comment: You need to `grease(slider)`.  You'll find `grease` in the squeak standard library.  Also, is `tweetContent` HTML from a source that you trust?

Comment: You have a js error. ReferenceError: address is not defined http://ngaio.dogpatchmedia.com/www:234. `$("#events").append('<div class="slide">' + address + '</div>').trigger('create');
`. This might be part of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing fullpage.js before your add the slides. 
Javascript is asynchronous and you need to be careful with that.

You should add the initialization of fullpage.js in the `success` statement of your ajax call. Just after you add the slides with javascript.

Comment: Thank you. Thats exatcly what I didnt understand was the order in which things happen in the scripts.

Comment: I always forget to do that :)